# How to use sync and Unless together in Cacheable? Any workaround?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I have a use case where I need to use sync and I don't want to cache if the method returns null. How can I do it?

```
@Cacheable(value = "abc", sync = true, unless = "#result!=null")
```

currently this is not supported in Spring.
I am using Spring 5.2.2

Comment: Can you maybe add more about your use case, e.g. why you don't want to cache a null. This to avoid the XY problem. Maybe there is a good solution, but not specifically to that what you are asking for.

Comment: @Cruftex Because I am hitting  a service which sometimes doesn't gives the result at first hit.

Comment: Basically, I don't want to Cache an error or any null value returned by the service I am hitting so that next time when same input goes and the service is running fine, I get my result

Comment: In case null is unexpected I would simply throw an exception in the method body instead. Callers of the method probably don't check for nulls consistently, so better catch this at a low level and throw a meaningful exception. If your service returns null, because there is no data, it might be better to return an Optional. OTOH, since Spring supports the caching of null values, it should be possible to check for it. Maybe a Spring expert can say more.